# Good practise to mainain serializable model to XMLs regarding different XSD versions

Tags: c#, xml, validation, xsd

Assume that I have XML file that is validated against schema. Moreover I have model which is serializable to above xml and validated against XSD schema.

During application lifecycle my model can be changed therefore it's XSD version changes.

E.g. version 1.0 
There was element:

```
   <xs:complexType name="SomeConfig">
    <xs:all>
      <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="ElementAlwaysValid" type="xs:boolean" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="SomeElement" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:all>
  </xs:complexType>
```

then in version 1.1 it occured that someone decided it to be like this:

```
  <xs:complexType name="SomeConfig">
    <xs:all>
      <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="ElementAlwaysValid" type="xs:boolean" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="1" nillable="true" name="SomeElement" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:all>
  </xs:complexType>
```

then in version 1.2 it was decided that: someElement is not required anymore.

```
 <xs:complexType name="SomeConfig">
    <xs:all>
      <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="ElementAlwaysValid" 
    </xs:all>
  </xs:complexType>
```

Here we have compatibility issues.

Once it could occur validation error that schema requires element "SomeElement" but it does not exists.

The other time it could occur error that schema does not require SomeElement but it exists.

Are there any good patterns how to cope with such compatibily issues?

I thought about converters or XSLT but maybe there are some good practise regarding this topic.

Comment: First, use semantic versioning (http://semver.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Using, for instance, this constants class:

```
namespace Q32345998_XsdVersion
{
    public static class Constants
    {
        public const string XsdNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema10.xsd";
        public const string SomeConfigRootName = "sc";
    }
}
```

you could split your objects into different namespaces depending on version. Each `SomeConfig` class will be decorated with these attributes:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlType(Namespace = Constants.XsdNamespace)]
[XmlRoot(Constants.SomeConfigRootName, Namespace = Constants.XsdNamespace, IsNullable = false)]
```

Then add backward/forward compliancy through explicit/implicit cast operators. Hence:

```
namespace Q32345998_XsdVersion.v10
{
    public partial class SomeConfig
    {
        public bool ElementAlwaysValid { get; set; }
        public string SomeElement { get; set; }
    }
}
namespace Q32345998_XsdVersion.v11
{
    public partial class SomeConfig
    {
        public bool ElementAlwaysValid { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(IsNullable = true)]
        public string SomeElement { get; set; }

        public static explicit operator v10.SomeConfig(v11.SomeConfig v11)
        {
            return new v10.SomeConfig() { ElementAlwaysValid = v11.ElementAlwaysValid, SomeElement = v11.SomeElement };
        }
    }
}
namespace Q32345998_XsdVersion.v12
{
    public partial class SomeConfig
    {
        public bool ElementAlwaysValid { get; set; }

        public static explicit operator v11.SomeConfig (v12.SomeConfig v12)
        {
            return new v11.SomeConfig() { ElementAlwaysValid = v12.ElementAlwaysValid, SomeElement = null };
        }
        public static explicit operator v10.SomeConfig(v12.SomeConfig v12)
        {
            return new v10.SomeConfig() { ElementAlwaysValid = v12.ElementAlwaysValid, SomeElement = null };
        }

    }
}
```

Use this like:

```
// convert from v1.2 to v1.1 and 1.0
v12.SomeConfig sc12 = new v12.SomeConfig() { ElementAlwaysValid = true };
v11.SomeConfig sc11 = (v11.SomeConfig)sc12;
v10.SomeConfig sc10 = (v10.SomeConfig)sc12;
// convert from v1.1 to 1.0
sc11 = new v11.SomeConfig() { ElementAlwaysValid = true, SomeElement=string.Empty };
sc10 = (v10.SomeConfig)sc11;
```

Although I think it would be more elegant to version your xsd and serialization objects, or add a version attribute to your SomeConfig.